# Running an If statement within a For loop to change last string

Tags: php, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to output an array that looks like this

```
[data, data],
[data, data],
[data, data]
```

The last string should be echoed without a comma.

My For loop looks like this:

```
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
    {
        echo "[" . $result[$i]->dato . ", " . $result[$i]->vaegt . "]";
        
        if ($i < $count) {
            echo ",<br>";
        }
    }
```

It echoes out the correct strings but the comma is still there in the last string.
It seems like the If statement is still reading the last string?

Comment: Use `implode()`

Comment: Your $i is always smaller than $count. Last element is $count-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check condition for n-1.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    echo "[" . $result[$i]->dato . ", " . $result[$i]->vaegt . "]";
    
    if ($i < $count-1) {
        echo ",<br>";
    }
}
```